# How to make a block of code run from a raw_input in python

Tags: python

Stack Overflow I have a question. I am very new to python but I am trying to make a hacking assistant that will run attacks and scans just by asking it too. I just started last night and wanted to make a basic port scanner I wrote the port scanner in another .py file now how do I make it run if the user types "port scanner" "Will you scan a port for me?" etc.
Also whenever I type joke it does not run the joke block of code it just runs the port scanner...

```
# coding: utf-8
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

if Home == "portscanner" or "Portscanner" or "Will you scan a port for     me?":
portscanner()


######This starts the code for the machine responding with jokes

if Home == "Tell me a joke" or "Joke" or "joke" or "do you know any     jokes?" or "Do you know any jokes":
    #Joke section this is purely cosmetic and funny for the user gonna add more features like this
from random import *
def joke():
joke1 = "I like telling UDP jokes because I don't care if you don't get them"
joke2 = "CAPS LOCK - Preventing Login Since 1980."
joke3 = "In a world without fences and walls, who needs Gates and Windows?"
joke4 = "I once had an idea.....oh wait nope that was my maker...I'm a program...I don't have ideas"
joke5 = "Programmers are tools for converting caffeine into code."
joke6 = "Hacking is like sex...You get in, you get out, and hope that you didn’t leave something that can be traced back to you."
joke7 = "!false - its funny because its true"
joke8 = "<joke>Joke Here</joke>"
joke9 = "Hide&Seek champion - ; - Since 1958"
headers = [joke1, joke2, joke3, joke4, joke5, joke6, joke7, joke8, joke9]
print headers[randint(0,8)]
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting and provide expected and actual functionality, and how you are setting `Home`

Comment: Also if you're already importing random, a better choice is (funnily) `random.choice()`

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with `scanner.py`:

```
def scan():
    # Do you scan
```

then in your main file get a string from user:

```
import scanner

Home = input()
if Home == "portscanner" or "Portscanner" or "Will you scan a port for me?":
    scanner.scan()
```

Comment: Thank you for responding I edited my code to what you have written here. It imports the module amazingly now but it does not give the user the raw_input where they can choose something other than port scanner...Could you help me?

Comment: user can write whatever he/she wants as an input and it goes to `Home` variable.what do you expect from user?

Comment: I want the user to choose what they want to happen. I only have a simple port scanner at the moment but I want to add 100's of features but at the moment a raw_input box for the user to type what they would like is not popping up it is just going straight to the port scanner. How do I fix this?